# geotools 20.5 error: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory could not be instantiated

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, geotools

I am working on a java project which required to convert WGS84 to UMT. I used geotools v20.5 to create a transform with following code:

```
transform = CRS.findMathTransform(
              CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true),
              CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true),
              false);
```

It was working correctly until geotools changed their repos.
Currently when I run the program, I will get a warning:

```
WARNING: Can't load a service for category "CRSAuthorityFactory". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CartesianAuthorityFactory could not be instantiated".
```

then with following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ONE
Execution failed for task ':Application.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
```

my environment: *Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenJDK 8 (64bit)*
I tested with other Windows machine, it hits same error.
Here are the libs I am using from org.geotools

```
def geotoolsVersion=20.5

    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-opengis', version: geotoolsVersion
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-referencing', version: geotoolsVersion
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-epsg-wkt', version: geotoolsVersion
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-geometry', version: geotoolsVersion
```

As you may notice I am using *gt-epsg-wkt* instead of those ones with db since I may not have write permission to some directories in production. But I tested other plugins with db, still hitted same error.
I tried to debug which part of code in geotools caused that error and I found out.
The error started at the last line ***Units.autoCorrect(...)*** of following codes in **Parser.java** class in **gt-referencing** lib.

```
    /**
     * Parses an "UNIT" element. This element has the following pattern:
     *
     * <blockquote>
     *
     * <code>
     * UNIT["<name>", <conversion factor> {,<authority>}]
     * </code>
     *
     * </blockquote>
     *
     * @param parent The parent element.
     * @param unit The contextual unit. Usually {@link SI#METRE} or {@link SI#RADIAN}.
     * @return The "UNIT" element as an {@link Unit} object.
     * @throws ParseException if the "UNIT" can't be parsed.
     * @todo Authority code is currently ignored. We may consider to create a subclass of {@link
     *     Unit} which implements {@link IdentifiedObject} in a future version.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Quantity<T>> Unit<T> parseUnit(final Element parent, final Unit<T> unit)
            throws ParseException {
        final Element element = parent.pullElement("UNIT");
        final String name = element.pullString("name");
        final double factor = element.pullDouble("factor");
        final Map<String, ?> properties = parseAuthority(element, name);
        element.close();
        Unit<T> finalUnit = (factor != 1) ? unit.multiply(factor) : unit;
        return Units.autoCorrect(finalUnit);
    }
```

Then I stepped into it and found out following method in **DefaultUnitParser.java** class in gt-referencing lib

```
DefaultUnitParser.getInstance() 
//this method returns null, with error said org.geotools.measure.units failed to instantialize.
```

I am totally lost now, why it was working and sunddly not working after they changed their remote repo?!
If you need further info from me, please leave a comment and I am still awaiting for a solution since I cannot easily change geotools lib. 
Thanks all

BTW I confirmed it gets correct WKT via code: EPSG:4326 or EPSG:3857

***UPDATE***
I changed the geotools version down to **12.5** which is written on their website https://geotools.org/about.html and switched JTS lib to com.vividsolutions.jts then it is working now. I think I may need to raise an issue on their github.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793283/org-getools-nosuchfielderror-meter or something is up with the way you construct your jar?

Comment: I think that's not the same problem as I had. I add those jars according the geotools architecture page https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/architecture.html . And I sure it was working until they changed their remote repo

Comment: I changed geotools version down to 12.5 which depens on com.vividsolutions.jts:1.13 instead of org.locationtech.jts and that issue has been resolved and working. So I think the issue only in the latest stable build of geotools

Comment: Not the current stable build is 23.x not 12.x despite what the about page says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to solving this sort of issue is to see what `gradle` is pulling in as dependecies using `gradle -q dependencies` - if you have a well constructed build you should see something like:

```
+--- org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.16.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-opengis:23.1
|    +--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
|    +--- systems.uom:systems-common-java8:0.7.2
|    |    +--- tec.uom:uom-se:1.0.8
|    |    |    +--- javax.measure:unit-api:1.0
|    |    |    \--- tec.uom.lib:uom-lib-common:1.0.2
|    |    |         \--- javax.measure:unit-api:1.0
|    |    +--- si.uom:si-quantity:0.7.1
|    |    |    \--- javax.measure:unit-api:1.0
|    |    \--- si.uom:si-units-java8:0.7.1
|    |         +--- javax.measure:unit-api:1.0
|    |         +--- tec.uom:uom-se:1.0.8 (*)
|    |         \--- si.uom:si-quantity:0.7.1 (*)
|    \--- javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3
+--- org.geotools:gt-epsg-wkt:23.1
|    +--- org.geotools:gt-referencing:23.1
|    |    +--- org.ejml:ejml-ddense:0.34
|    |    |    \--- org.ejml:ejml-core:0.34
|    |    +--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
|    |    +--- org.geotools:gt-metadata:23.1
```

If however you see something like:

```
+--- org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.16.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-opengis:23.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-epsg-wkt:23.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-geometry:23.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-referencing:23.1
+--- org.geotools:gt-main:23.1
\--- org.geotools:gt-metadata:23.1
```

then something is wrong. From my (brief) experiments with gradle it seems that you need something like:

```
repositories {
     maven { url "http://download.java.net/maven/2" }
     maven { url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/" }
     maven { url "http://maven.geo-solutions.it/" }
     maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
```

to make sure that gradle can find all the dependencies that you (and GeoTools) needs. Note if you are using snapshots of GeoTools you will need `https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/` instead of `https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/`.

Comment: Hello Ian, thanks again for helpping me solved that issue. Just post the link to jira case: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/issues/GEOT-6604